# How to output a required number of significant digits for a number

Tags: javascript, json

I have below JSON which I have to display on browser ...

```
{
  "testDoubleArr": [1, 2.0, 3.45],
  "testStr3": "SHA",
  "testDouble1": 12.56,
  "testDouble2": 1.0,
  "testStr1": "OMG"
}
```

On browser it get display in below format ...

```
{
  "testDoubleArr": [1, 2, 3.45],
  "testStr3": "SHA",
  "testDouble1": 12.56,
  "testDouble2": 1,
  "testStr1": "OMG"
}
```

It has removed all zeros if the value only contains zeros after the decimal, while I have to show them without converting it into string.

How do I specify the number of significant digits for JavaScript numbers?

Comment: They are the same thing - there is only one `Number` type in javascript.

Comment: _"I have to show them without converting it into string"_ And how do you expect to do that?

Comment: I want to show them with zero means "testDouble2": 1.0  and not "testDouble2": "1.0"

Comment: @PrabhatNigam I think the point being made in other comments is that you are absolutely required to convert to string in some capacity in order to display to user. Currently you are setting the numerical values as Number types in javascript. When outputting these, you will drop insignificant digits unless you do something to specifically specify the string representation you are looking for.  If you are concerned about matching the exact input values without transforming the display (or performing any calculations on the numbers), then you should use string fields as input.

Comment: Also, if you are just trying parrot out the input string, you may be best off not parsing the JSON prior to the point that you are displaying this string.  If you never parse the string into memory, the string will remain intact for display.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the number of significant digits to decimal.

```
var num = 1;
num.toFixed(2); // returns the string "1.00"
```

However, if the number has MORE significant digits, they will be dropped:

```
var num = 1.123456789;
var num.toFixed(2) // returns the string "1.12"
```

Comment: @ Chad, this solution is not valid for all the scenarios. First at all it will drop remaining numbers after point. And second thing it will convert the integer number to double number too. eg 1 will be shown as 1.00, which is not reasonable.

Comment: All JavaScript numbers are floating point. There is only one number type. Your question doesn't really explain all of your requirements.

Comment: My only requirement is, if value is 1 then it should show 1 not "1" , if value is 1.0 then it should show 1.0 not "1.0", while displaying it in json on UI.

Comment: I want json should be printed on UI as it works in http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#about, this tool prints JSON as it is irrespective of the type of value. for the sample json you can use below within that tool ...

Comment: {
  "data" : {
    "testDoubleArr" : [ 1.3 ],
    "testDouble2" : 0.0,
    "InterestRate" : 0.0,
    "testInt1" : 0,
    "testBool3" : true,
    "testInt2" : 0,
    "testBool2" : true,
    "testInt3" : 0,
    "testBool1" : true,
    "Month" : "UMG",
    "testStr3" : "SHA",
    "testStr2" : "HAMP",
    "testDouble3" : 0.0
  },
  "header" : {
    "modelName" : "Test Tenant Version",
    "majorVersion" : 1,
    "transactionId" : "2",
    "minorVersion" : 0,
    "date" : "2015-01-30T11:18:00.000"
  }
}